# Flink application doesn't seem to run when using a large avro schema

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, flink-streaming

I have a flink application written in Java that reads messages from a given kafka topic and uses a given subject name to get latest schema from schema registry. It uses this schema to deserialize the message and put it into an s3 bucket in parquet format. However, the application seems to run when I am using a schema of a small size , about 10 fields. But, I am unable to run the application when I am using a schema of larger size about 160 fields.

It results in an exception as below

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Could not serialize inputs.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.setInputs(StreamConfig.java:262)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Could not serialize inputs.

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.setVertexConfig(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:688)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:460)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:412)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:412)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:412)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.setChaining(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:378)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createJobGraph(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:179)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createJobGraph(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.getJobGraph(StreamGraph.java:934)
    at org.apache.flink.client.StreamGraphTranslator.translateToJobGraph(StreamGraphTranslator.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.client.FlinkPipelineTranslationUtil.getJobGraph(FlinkPipelineTranslationUtil.java:39)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.executors.PipelineExecutorUtils.getJobGraph(PipelineExecutorUtils.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.executors.LocalExecutor.getJobGraph(LocalExecutor.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.executors.LocalExecutor.execute(LocalExecutor.java:82)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1957)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1848)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1834)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1817)
    at com.thomsonreuters.connector.FlinkS3MultiSink.kafkaS3ConsumeData(FlinkS3MultiSink.java:141)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.UTFDataFormatException
Caused by: java.io.UTFDataFormatException

    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:2170)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:2013)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:872)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.typeutils.SerializableAvroSchema.writeObject(SerializableAvroSchema.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1145)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1379)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:624)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.writeObjectToConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:546)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.setInputs(StreamConfig.java:260)
    ... 21 more
```

Kafka Source logic

```
final KafkaSource<GenericRecordWrapper> source = KafkaSource.<GenericRecordWrapper>builder()
                    .setBootstrapServers(connectorProperties.getBootstrapServers())
                    .setTopics(topicList)
                    .setGroupId(connectorProperties.getGroupId())
                    .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
                    .setProperty(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, connectorProperties.getSecurityProtocol())
                    .setProperty(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, connectorProperties.getSaslMechanism())
                    .setProperty(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, connectorProperties.getSaslJaasConfig())
                    .setProperties(connectorProperties.getKafkaConsumerConfig())
                    .setDeserializer(KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.of(new CustomGenDeserializer(avroSchema, connectorProperties.getSchemaRegistryUrl()))).build();
```

Deserialization logic

```
private final transient Schema schema;
private final DeserializationSchema<?> deserializationSchema;
    public CustomGenDeserializer(final Schema avroSchema, final String registryUrl)
    {
        schema = avroSchema;
        deserializationSchema = ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forGeneric(avroSchema, registryUrl);
    }

@Override
    public GenericRecordWrapper deserialize(final ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> consumerRecord) throws Exception
    {
        GenericRecordWrapper obj = new GenericRecordWrapper();
        try
        {
            obj.setTopicName(consumerRecord.topic());
            GenericRecord genericRecord = (GenericRecord) deserializationSchema.deserialize(consumerRecord.value());
            log.info("key: {}, topic: {}, partition: {}, offset: {}", consumerRecord.key() != null ? new String(consumerRecord.key()) : consumerRecord.key(),
                     consumerRecord.topic(), consumerRecord.partition(), consumerRecord.offset());
            obj.setGenericRecord(genericRecord);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("Error deserializing record with topic-name: {}, partition: {}, offset: {}, timestamp: {}, key: {}, value: {}",
                      consumerRecord.topic(), consumerRecord.partition(), consumerRecord.offset(), consumerRecord.timestamp(),
                      consumerRecord.key() != null ? new String(consumerRecord.key()) : consumerRecord.key(),
                      consumerRecord.value() != null ? new String(consumerRecord.value()) : consumerRecord.value());
            return null;
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

I have tried to run the application when the topic was empty and when it had exactly one message. In both scenarios, I am getting the same error as above. From the error, it seems like it is unable to serialize inputs. (I suspect it to be the schema because it only happens when I use the large schema). which led me to believe that I may need to configure the application differently when using a large schema.

I know that the schema I am using is perfectly fine and is in an expected avro format as I am using it to produce message and also consume messages from a different consumer springboot application.

Please advise if I need to using any specific configs in a flink application when using large schema.

Application version details
Flink : 1.13.2
Java : 1.11